# Is there an optimal way to disable parent scroll

Tags: react-native, scrollview, flatlist

I am trying to disable parent scroll, when scrolling up/down in the child component (child component is a horizontal `FlatList`). Is there an optimal way?

```
   <ScrollView scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}>
    <Header />
    <FlatList
      horizontal={true}
      data={cards}
      renderItem={() => (
        <Pressable onPressIn={() => setScrollEnabled(false)} onPressOut={() => setScrollEnabled(true)}>
          <ScrollingCard />
        </Pressable>
      )}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.toString()}
    />
    {cards.map((item) => <ScrollingCard key={`vertical-${item}`} item={item} type="Vertical" />)}
  </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a state:-

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    username: "Mark White",
    enableScrollViewScroll: true
})
```

Handle state when scroll:-

```
const onEnableScroll = (value) => {
    setData({
        ...data,
        enableScrollViewScroll: value
    })
}
```

Inside component:-

```
         <ScrollView
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            scrollEnabled={data.enableScrollViewScroll}>
           <View>
                <FlatList
                    onTouchStart={() => {
                        onEnableScroll(false);
                    }}
                    onMomentumScrollEnd={() => {
                        onEnableScroll(true);
                    }}
                  ...
                />
            </View>
         </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const ScrollEnabledContext = createContext(null);

const Parent = () => {
    const ref = useRef(null);

    const setIsEnabled = (bool) => {
        ref.current?.setNativeProps({ scrollEnabled: bool });
    };

    return (
        <ScrollEnabledContext.Provider value={setIsEnabled}>
            <ScrollView ref={ref} nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
                <ChildScrollView />
            </ScrollView>
        </ScrollEnabledContext.Provider>
    );
};

const ChildScrollView = () => {
    const value = useContext(ScrollEnabledContext);

    return (
        <ScrollView onTouchStart={() => value(false)} onTouchEnd={() => value(true)}>
            ....
        </ScrollView>
    );
};
```

It works without any re-renders and works way faster than setting state.